# How to set image url dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have inserted images and link as a other field like "www.google.com".

Now i want to make sure that when user click on image it should redirect user to corresponding link in new Tab.

```asp
<a href="javascript:;"> 
<img src="Admin/Gallery/<%#GetImage5 (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ID")))%>" class="img-responsive" alt=""> <img src="Admin/Gallery/<%#GetImage5 (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ID")))%>" class="color-img img-responsive" alt=""> 
 <a href="Admin/Gallery/<%#Eval("Linkname") %>"<i class="color-img img-responsive"></i>
 </a> 
</a>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code so we can see what you mean and what you tried/did wrong?

Comment: Show your code to find where you go wrong way

Comment: Please check it now.


                            <a href="javascript:;">
                                <img src="Admin/Gallery/<%#GetImage5 (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ID")))%>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                <img src="Admin/Gallery/<%#GetImage5 (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ID")))%>" class="color-img img-responsive" alt="">
                                 <a href="Admin/Gallery/<%#Eval("Linkname") %>"<i class="color-img img-responsive"></i></a>
                                

                            </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To redirect the user to another URL when an image is clicked you need to surround the image with an anchor tag(`<a></a>`) which has a **valid** `href` attribute, needs to be something like `href="http://www.google.com"` not `href="javascript:;"`
2. To open the link in a new tab you must add `target="_blank"` to the anchor.

**Code behind:**

```
public string ImagePath { get; set; }
public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImagePath = "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/fruit/fruit-04.jpg";
    ImageUrl = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<a href='<%: ImageUrl %>' target="_blank">
    <img src='<%: ImagePath %>' style="width: 200px; height: 180px;" />
</a>
```